# Can't save ballerina code create using composer

Tags: ballerina, ballerina-composer

when I try to save ballerina code create using composer flowing error occur.

```
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'open' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Invalid URL
```

How I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you please specify operating system you have used?

Comment: Microsoft Windows 8.1

Comment: I tried with my Windows 7 instance but unfortunately could not reproduce this behaviour. Could you please explain the situation bit more. is it happening for a particular .bal code or is it happening for all? If its a particular .bal please provide the code. is it fresh 0.90 pack or did you apply any patch on it? If its a bug, we can raise a github issue on github compose repository.

Answer (score 1):

recheck environment variable for ballerina bin path.

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to the file service connection being closed by the OS after being idle for sometime. This connection closing can happen unexpectedly and if the issue reproduces frequently, please create an issue at [composer issues](https://github.com/ballerinalang/composer/issues)